# Spring MVC resource not found on start

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

So I know there are dozens of posts similar to this, but unfortunately none of those have helped me.  I am simply trying to get a demo Spring MVC project up and running.  I am trying to run a template project provided by Heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-heroku-eclipse).  I have tried many combinations of settings to no avail.  Here are the default settings:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Spring-Hibernate-Template</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/people/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

</bean>

<beans profile="default">
    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource"/>        
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="prod">
    <bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
        <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['DATABASE_URL']}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="url" value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + ':' + @dbUrl.getPort() + @dbUrl.getPath() }"/>
        <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }"/>
        <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <!-- change this to 'verify' before running as a production app -->
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>

</beans>
```

PersonController.java:

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String listPeople(Map<String, Object> map) {

        map.put("person", new Person());
        map.put("peopleList", personService.listPeople());

        return "people";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person, BindingResult result) {

        personService.addPerson(person);

        return "redirect:/people/";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{personId}")
    public String deletePerson(@PathVariable("personId") Integer personId) {

        personService.removePerson(personId);

        return "redirect:/people/";
    }
}
```

And I have a 'people.jsp' file at webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/people/jsp

My server.xml context element for the Tomcat server looks like:

```
<Context docBase="facultypublicationsdb" path="/facultypublicationsdb" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:facultypublicationsdb"/></Host>
```

Every time I run this on Tomcat at (`http://localhost:8080/facultypublicationsdb/`), I get the following:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /facultypublicationsdb/

type Status report

message /facultypublicationsdb/

description The requested resource (/facultypublicationsdb/) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.21
```

I am running this on Ubuntu through eclipse.  I notice that no .war is being copied over to the `/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps` directory.  Is that supposed to occur?

Any ideas?

Comment: For one thing, I noticed that in your applicationContext.xml, you have got two closing beans tags at the end of the xml file.

Comment: @blackpanther There are two opening beans tags as well.

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox Yes, I am using maven.

Comment: @JeremyG Are your maven dependencies included in the deployment assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking two things.

First change your web.xml file to map the dispatcher servlet to `/`.  This causes the dispatcher servlet to be used when no other mappings are found for a request, instead of for every request.  This is important if you have resources such as CSS and Javascript.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/people/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Next, if using Eclipse, open your projects properties (Click project in project, explorer Alt+Enter).  Then go to deployment assembly.  Make sure that all of your projects resources are included here, especially any maven dependencies.  If you notice that dependencies are missing click the add button and select them.

You may also want to ensure that your controllers are being picked up by component scanning.  Ensure that your controllers are in the `com.example` package.

Comment: The controllers are the in correct package.  The dependencies are added to the deployment assembly. I changed the url-pattern to / but no change unfortunately.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that the dependencies were not added to the assembly.  Thanks for the suggestion.  After adding them to the assembly, I continued to get a few more errors, but downloading the m2eclipse error cleared those up.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you need to specify `method = RequestMethod.GET` in `listPeople` method. There could be many small things that could cause `404 error`. Could you upload this code on GitHub and I will look into it.